# Difference between std:random shuffle() and Collections.shuffle

Tags: java, c++, shuffle

I tried multiple times to understand why each of `std:random shuffle()` in C++, and `Collections.shuffle` in Java.

With the same seed don't give the same generated sequence, However it's supposed that both of them is uniformly distributed.

I appreciate if someone can help me to know with example when I can generate the same value.
I implemented an algorithm used random generated values as initial value, I have a result of C++ and I want to validate my algorithm which is implemented in  Java.

Comment: Umm not the same algorithm...isn't it obvious? Only the distribution of the end result is guaranteed nothing else between multiple shuffle implementation

Answer (score 1):

The reason that they produce different results is that their random number generators produce different sequences of random numbers. What I've done when I need random number sequences that are the same for different compilers or languages is to generate a sequence of numbers and store it in a text file, then use that text file as the source of random numbers.